# Missing logs in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

This is an awful question, I know, but already for 15 minutes can't find where to see logs in IntelliJ, where should I press?
Here is a screenshot[image: I]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bottom line of your window:

4: Run

That should pop up automatically if you run your application.